# UISearchController don't reset searchBar

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uisearchcontroller

Sounds simple, but I can't find anything about the searchBar being reset. I'm assuming that the default behaviour is that the text in the searchBar managed by the UISearchController is reset when the search button on the keyboard is tapped. I don't want this behaviour, instead I want the text to persist in the searchBar after the results controller is dismissed. I use the `active` property to control when to dismiss the results controller:

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {

    // Do some real search and other stuff...

    self.searchController.active = NO;
}
```

What am I missing here? I tried to use the delegate methods to keep the typed text in, but it seems it's cleared even before the `willDismissSearchController:` method is called.

Comment: Please share the code how are you tried to persist the text is searchbar.

Comment: When you set `active = NO` yes that will clear it. If you want to persist it you can try saving it to a variable before that method is called then just re-setting it on `willDismissSearchController`

Comment: @Poles there is no such code because I don't know how to do it. I only kept the text in the variable but this is not persisting it, it's just a workaround and not a good one.

Comment: @zsteed This is what I do now but it's not good enough, I was hoping there is a simple way.